# My question is thermodynamic

Tags: thermodynamics

What can I use to cover a mirror that is a backsplash at my stove which protect it from shattering with high heat? 44x28 inches

Comment: Please add specifications to your question (a better title would do as well).  We could put fire bricks in front of a mirror, but I assume you have something else in mind.

Comment: I have a mirror back to my induction hob. Sometimes the frying pan touches the mirror - not broken or cracked.

Comment: It depends on the glass used for the mirror, some glass can take a large temperature gradient and even be used as a cooktop while others shatter in simple oven use. Other option would be to cover the mirror, but that defeats purpose of having the mirror.